# Extract value of formula based cell through if statement

Tags: excel

I have a sheet where a cell D2 has a formula i.e.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("exception",$A2))
```

It returns TRUE or FALSE. Now i have another cell where it should return the heading of the column if it has TRUE in it. So I tried :

```
=IF(D2="TRUE","Unhandled Exception")
```

But as it returns FALSE whatever I do, I think its because D2 has a formula in it so it is not returning the value even if TRUE is present.

Comment: If it's Boolean, did you try `=IF(D2, ...)`? It's not going to be equal to the string `"TRUE"`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem yesterday. 
Try changing your formula to

```
=IF(D2=TRUE,"Unhandled Exception")
```

Since the cell will have the value True, not the string "true"

Comment: it worked, thanks. Can i return the cell value(D1) which has the string instead of writing the whole text??

Comment: If you mean the "Unhandled Exception" is written in D1, You can just do:     
=IF(D2=TRUE,D1)